# How to install a software and then run java class from batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which runs a java class file.
But I want to install a software before running the class file?
When he runs batch file again then it should not ask for installing the software again.

file.bat

```
@echo off
cd ACR122U_MSI_Winx64_1120_P
Setup.exe
java -cp zpay-client-1.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar;.\resources com.abc.posgui.LicenseValidator
```

But this asks to install software everytime and does not execute java class. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the Java doesn't work have you tried to launch the batch without "Setup.exe"?

```
@echo off
cd ACR122U_MSI_Winx64_1120_P
REM Setup.exe
java -cp zpay-client-1.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar;.\resources com.abc.posgui.LicenseValidator
```

Otherwise, are you sure that the installation has stopped?